# How to use a txt file as command line argument?

Tags: c#, console, command-line-arguments

I have a .txt file like this: 
6 4
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
1 2 4 5

How can I use this as command line argument in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you intend to give your program data `program.exe < data.txt`, this is called *reading from standard input*. You can do this via .NET's [Console.OpenStandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx55zca2.aspx) with

```
new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput())
```

---

Alternatively, if you'd rather your program be run `program.exe data.txt`, start with

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
    File.ReadLines(args[0])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accept the file name in the command line (along with path) and open the file in your application, read it line by line and process all the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Solution Explorer` > `Right click on project file` > `Select Properties from context menu`. This opens the properties window of the project. Now Go to `Debug tab` > Go to `Start options section` in right pane. Put the full file path inside `Command line arguments` text box as shown below:

```
< "D:\Rasik\input01.txt"
```

[image]

Then you can write code as usual and you will start getting input from the file:

```
class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var textInFirstLineOfFile = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```