# Not able to pass text file(.txt) as command line argument to console application

Tags: c#, file, console-application, command-line-arguments

I want to pass Text(.txt) file from command line arguments as a parameter to my console application.

This is a structure of my console application:[image]

Now i want to pass **SampleFile.txt** file from command line argument which is in my project as you can see in image and print output of my txt file.

How to do this?

Can anybody tell me step by step procedure to do this as i am very much new to console application.

Comment: But you are not using `args` to get file path.

Comment: Do you need it in debugger?

Comment: Is the SampleFile.txt being copied to your output directory? In the properties make sure `Copy to Output Directory` is set to `Copy Always` or `Copy if newer`

Comment: @X-TECH:yes i want i args only.i have just copy pasted this code and i dont have much idea about command line arguments.

Comment: Downvote Reasons pleasee

Comment: The reason you're being downvoted is because the question is very basic - you could have found the answer with 5 minutes on google. This site premiers good, well thought out questions for nontrivial problems.

Comment: Yeah i have google alot about this but i didnt found ans like How Dennis,MarioG and charithj have given so i have asked this and as i have already specified in my question that i am very much new to console app.so cant novice programmer ask question on stackoverflow

Comment: If you hover over the downvote arrow on the question you'll see a small "reason for downvote" box. This question falls under Does not show any research effort part. My second result on bing is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx, which explains exactly how to do what you're asking.

Comment: @EricJohansson:I will do remember this thing next time.Thanks for guiding me

Comment: Related post - [How to use a txt file as command line argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12770561/465053)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to process "SampleFile.txt", when debugging your application, then:

- right click on project in Solution Explorer, select "Properties";
- switch to "Debug" page on the left;
- type "SampleFile.txt" (with full path, if required), under "Start options/Command line arguments";
- save project;
- use `args[0]` to access file name you've passed.

[image]

Comment: but after deploying this project on server how this file would be access as you are specifying local path like d drive

Comment: This is just a way to build command line arguments. There are two different cases. The 1st one, when you're debugging application - in this case you'll use file name, passed by Visual Studio, when it starts debugging session. The 2nd one, when your application is used after deployment - int this case it will use file name, passed by user. In other words, "d:\foo\bar\SampleFile.txt" won't be "remembered" by your application.

Comment: It won't be a problem, the start options command line argument is only a default to be passed to your program when you debug with F5. When you run the program from a command prompt you'll always need to supply your own argument.

Answer (score 4):

When you right click on the project and go to `Properties` there should be a tab called `Debug` containing an option for setting command line arguments. There you can put the filename.

```
SampleFile.txt
```

The filename is then found in the `args` array when starting the application.

```
string fileName = args[0];
```

Comment: in commandlineargument option do i need to specify full path like d of e of f drive

Comment: No you don't need to specify the full path - it'll be relative to the .exe as default.

Answer (score 3):

Copy your file always to output directory.

[image]

Add file path to command line arguments

[image]

Then you will get "SampleFile.txt" as a arg in your `main` method.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string yourFile = args[0];
}
```